# Remove web address from string

Tags: java

Input is

```
Catch up on all episodes and series at ChannelChooser.  .channelchooser.com/ - Cached - Similar
```

I want to the remove web address and terms like cached,similar.I need to extract only text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what context? Are you pulling this from a page? Need more info.

Comment: You are not really asking a question and instead telling us what you want to do. Please read the FAQ, because we can help if you have something for us to look at. Your explanation makes no sense!

Comment: can you list down all the words that you want to omit from the input?

Comment: @emaillenin:The words like .channelchooser.com/ -Cached -Similar has to be removed. My output should be like this Catch up on all episodes and series at ChannelChooser.

Comment: @dmackerman:I want to extract the document description or snippet.The snippet was extracted using jericho html parser which contains html tags.I was able to remove html tags but snippet contains web address www.wikipedia.org, ..channelchooser/ -Cached -Similar.So i need to remove this.Using regex,it is possible to remove www.wikipedia.org but i cannot remove ..channelchooser/ -Cached -Similar

Comment: @Aruna use String replace to replace those two words. use Regex Replace /(.*)\.com\// to replace websites.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the classes in java.util.regex package that brings pattern matching using regular expressions into Java core. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

(This applies to Java 6)